# Не подключается к сокет серверу

Tags: php, websocket

Добрый вечер. Запускаю веб сокет сервер на компьютере и пытаюсь подключиться к нему через клиент. Если в клиенте прописать localhost:8082 то конектится, но как только я пытаюсь вместо локал хоста прописать глобальный ip компьютера, клиент отказывается соединятся.Работаю на open server. 
Вот так выглядит клиент

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){

var socket = new WebSocket("ws://ip:8082");
var status = document.querySelector("#status");

socket.onopen = function() {
  status.innerHTML = "cоединение установлено" + "<br>";
};

socket.onclose = function(event) {
  if (event.wasClean) {
    status.innerHTML = 'cоединение закрыто';
  } else {
    status.innerHTML = 'соединения как-то закрыто';
  }
  status.innerHTML += '<br>код: ' + event.code + ' причина: ' + event.reason;
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  status.innerHTML += "пришли данные " + event.data + "<br>";
};

socket.onerror = function(event) {
  status.innerHTML = "ошибка " + event.message;
};


//в рамках onload
document.forms["messages"].onsubmit = function(){
  var fname = this.fname.value;
  var msg   = this.msg.value;
  socket.send(fname + ' ' + msg);
  return false;
}
}
</script>
```

Вот код сервера

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
        ),
        8082
    );

    $server->run();
```

Comment: Глобальный - это за NAT'ом или глобальный = в локальной сети?

Comment: глобальный это за NAT

Comment: Статичный? Порт открыт на машине?

Comment: Да адрес статичный порт открыт